# How does one mask neurons in Masked Autoencoders?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, torch, autoencoder

I learned about Masked AutoEncoders in this [course](https://sites.google.com/view/berkeley-cs294-158-sp20/home) and am now trying to code it. I am following Kaparthy's implementation over [here](https://github.com/karpathy/pytorch-made/blob/master/made.py).

I am unable to understand what's going on in the following lines -

```
    # sample the order of the inputs and the connectivity of all neurons
    self.m[-1] = np.arange(self.nin) if self.natural_ordering else rng.permutation(self.nin)
    for l in range(L):
        self.m[l] = rng.randint(self.m[l-1].min(), self.nin-1, size=self.hidden_sizes[l])
    
    # construct the mask matrices
    masks = [self.m[l-1][:,None] <= self.m[l][None,:] for l in range(L)]
    masks.append(self.m[L-1][:,None] < self.m[-1][None,:])
```

I understand the concept of the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03509) though. Basically, each output should only be conditioned on its corresponding or prior input. That means output y_1 should depend on x_1, y_2 should depend on x_1 and x_2.